# Selecting an item from a listview

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

With research and support, I have created a list of items populated through JSON data. I would want that when user click on one of the arrays of item, it would redirect them to another activity that would provide them with more information about it. With help, I have tried to work out the code, and even with assistance, my attempt so far have been unsuccessful.

In particular, I am encountering the followings errors in this section of the code:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                        intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                        startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                    }

                }
```

where I receiving errors such has:

"The method onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) of type ItemClickListener must override or implement a supertype method"

"No enclosing instance of the type EventsActivity is accessible in scope"

"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity"

The complete code is found below

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();

        //add interface ItemClickListener
        public interface ItemClickListener {


                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                        intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                        startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                    }

                }


                //catch in the second activity values 
                long id_item = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("id_item");
                int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id_item");


        //Adding reference to id of the item from your json we service in adapter


            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return items.get(position).id; 

    }
        }}





    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Update based around the great suggestions recieved**

I have updated the code based on the comments, and is now facing the following minor issues:
listview cannot be resolved, an error generated in the following line:

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
```

I have also encounter a minor formating issue which I have tried to resolve using right click > source > format, but the error still lies

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        }
```

Complete updated code below

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        }





    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
```

**Update 2**
I have received the below message from logcat. I have already cleaned my project, and have already verified that the activity is referenced in the manifest. I believe this could potentially be an issue with the below code.

Logcat message:

```
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1481
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.EventsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.dooba.beta.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:54)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-04 20:00:30.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 11 more
```

The updated activity code:

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String URL_WEB_SERVICE = "http://dooba.ca/analytics/ed.php";
    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> container;
    private ArrayList<Events_List> items;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_list_layout);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        container = new ArrayList<Events_List>();
        //download JSON
        listDownload();


        ListView s = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSingleClick);
        s.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                startActivity(intent); //start Activity
            }
        });
    }
    public void listDownload(){
        RequestQueue volley = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest json = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_WEB_SERVICE, null, ResponseListener(), ErrorListener());
        volley.add(json);
    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> ResponseListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //your JSON Array
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("list_item");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        container.add(convertirAnuncio(array.getJSONObject(i)));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                gv.setAdapter(new AdapterEvents(getApplicationContext(),container));
                }
            };
        };


    private Response.ErrorListener ErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
        };
    }

    //object JSON
    private final Events_List convertirAnuncio(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        long id = obj.getLong("id"); //id 
        String list_item_name = obj.getString("list_item_name"); 
        String list_item_description = obj.getString("list_item_description");
        String list_item_price = obj.getString("list_item_price");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(obj.getString("list_item_bac"));
        return new Events_List(id,list_item_name,list_item_description,list_item_price, uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
```

You are wrapping your method call to `setOnItemClickListener` which is completely on different scope thus giving you those errors, I dont know why you put interface within `onCreate` method, that is really a bad design.

**solution:**

just remove the `public interface ItemClickListener {` to use the reference of the class instead of `ItemClickListener`.

**EDIT:**

```
ListView s = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_to_list_view);
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about public interface. I have updated my initial post with an updated code, and where I am experiencing minor issues. If you could kindly advise, that would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: @user3827788 you dont jave a field listview you need to create one just like you did on your gv

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. It makes more sense now, the last small error I am trying to figure out is the following: "void is an invalid type for the variable onItemClick" generated from line          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Thanks a lot, your help has been tremendous.

Comment: @user3827788 you forgot to add the closing parenthesis,see edit above

Comment: Thanks a lot of your input. This has resolved the issue I had with formatting, and everything seemed to be fine until I ran it, and unexpectedly encountered a nullpointer exception error. I have added the logcat message along with the updated activity code under update 2 section in my initial post. Thanks a lot for all of your help.

Comment: @user3827788 that would be on differnte question

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
removing your interface code and getItem code.. this is all you need to make the itemClickListener to work.

```
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(EventsActivity.this,EventSingleItemActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id_item", id);//this is id of the item that you said it. for example id:5544323 from your JSON web service
                        intent.putExtra("position", position); //order position in listview 0-1-2-3...
                        startActivity(intent); //start Activity
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I have updated my initial post with an updated code, and where I am experiencing minor issues. If you could kindly advise, that would be helpful. Thank you